# Существенное отличие в скорости LIKE %% и оператора = в SQL в сторону оператора LIKE (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, mariadb

я сейчас был повергнут в шок
Я выполняю запрос (В базе 1млн строк)
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE '%yandex.ru%' ORDER BY id ASC;`
Получил результат: `65547 всего, Запрос занял 0.0030 сек.`

При этом я делаю запрос:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'test@yandex.ru' ORDER BY id ASC;`. Получаю результат `5 всего, Запрос занял 2.1431 сек` в 2 секунды. Я не понимаю, почему такая огромная разница в скорости запроса. Да, я сделал `ADD INDEX` на поле `email`. Но мне надо по большей части выполнять запросы через оператор `=`, чтобы получать конкретный емайл, а не схожие.

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE email LIKE 'test@yandex.ru' ORDER BY id ASC` с результатом: `Запрос занял 2.0724 сек`

Comment: Ситуация стабильно так выглядит ? т.е. если 10 раз подряд выполнить через раз то один то другой запрос время так же отличается ? Кроме того любые вопросы со скоростью работы запросов невозможно решать не видя плана выполнения запросов (которые получаются с помощью explain)

Comment: @Mike https://imgur.com/a/AxtT6Z0
Да, ситуация повторяется регулярно. 10 запросов из 10 показывают примерно одинаковый результат. По 2 сек = или LIKE и по 0.02 LIKE %%

Comment: очень странно, но в планах он не показывает даже что есть подходящий индекс. ощущение как будто его нет. проверьте что он есть и выполните analyze table. после посмотрите не изменилось ли что либо

Comment: но даже без индекса ситуация какая то мистическая

Comment: @Mike вы были правы, накосячил с созданием индекса. То есть он вроде был, но его не было)
Пересоздал и все ок теперь
Спасибо огромное за помощь!